# What's the effect of "weights" argument in caret::glmnet() function?

Tags: r, glmnet

I would like to found out what's happening if a customized weights list (not all equalling to 1 as default) is passed to `glmnet()`. I have looked into the `glmnet` package  [@github: glmnet](https://github.com/cran/glmnet) but could not figure out what's going underneath. Is it the same as up-sampling by duplicating the minority observations?

Comment: Something like this? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196614/what-are-the-weights-for-in-predict-function-in-r

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't think that's the answer. I know how to assign `weights` to `glmnet()` or `cv.glmnet()`. What I want to do is to understand how the weights will be used and what are the effects of using weights.

Answer (score 0):

In [glmnet vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf) by Trevor Hasties et al, "weights" is explained to be used to reconstruct deviance during convergency process, therefore impacting the final fitted model.